# How to set the Question width

Tags: enumerate, alignment

I want to bring XXX and YY in the first line in question number 2. I do not know how to do it

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tabto}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

% Margins
\usepackage[
top=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
left=20mm,
right=20mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\TabPositions{13cm, 15cm}
\begin{enumerate}
\item What is your name? \tab XXX \tab YY 
\item What is your name? What is your name? What is your name? What is your name? What is your name? What is your name?
\tab XXX \tab YY 
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `parbox` to get the desired result. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

% Margins
\usepackage[
top=2.5cm,
bottom=2.5cm,
left=20mm,
right=20mm
]{geometry}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \parbox[t]{125mm}{What is your name?}
      \parbox[t]{20mm}{XXX}
      \parbox[t]{20mm}{YY}
\item \parbox[t]{125mm}{What is your name? Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam
        voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea
        rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
        }
      \parbox[t]{20mm}{XXX}
      \parbox[t]{20mm}{YY}
\end{enumerate}
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Adjust the spacing according to your need/taste.

Comment: I have to do it in nested enumerate. I asked a new question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/694315/how-to-set-the-question-width-in-nested-enumerate